# Where can I find all the properties for customization in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to create my own style, like 'ggplot', and I'm looking for a dictionary or a guide where I can find all the customizable properties. At the end of this [page](https://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html) of the documentation of matplotlib there is a file called 'matplotlibrc' and i want to know if that files contains all the possible options on customization or there is something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the example file contains all possible parameters. This file is embedded into each documentation built; and there is a test that ensures that whenever a new parameter is added or removed, this file is updated. So you can consider it being complete.

However, make sure to always refer to the version of the documentation that corresponds to your matplotlib version.

The most up to date version at any time is at

- https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html

while for example the version of matplotlib 3.0.3 would be available through

- https://matplotlib.org/3.0.3/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html

Comment: It is possible to call a function to know all the possible options in a specific characteristic. For example if I want to know all the styles availables I use the print(plt.style.available) but if I want to know all the line styles, can I use a print(lines.linestyle.available)?

Comment: No, you would need to refer to the [documentation about linestyles](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_linestyle).